# Vim mapping behaving strangely

Tags: vim

I have the mapping shown below, in my `~/.vimrc`. However, this mapping also hijacks the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. So, whenever I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it executes the `tabedit %` command. I am using gvim 7.3

```
nnoremap <C-m> :tabedit %<CR>
```

Can anyone fix this so that it doesn't hijack the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**< C-m>** maps to the enter key (C-M and CR both do); it's not hijacking it, you're telling it to run **:tabedit %** every time you hit enter. I would suggest a different mapping.

See *:h key-notation* for more information.

Comment: How come? the vim documentation says that `<C-...> is the control-key` so <C-m> should map to Ctrl+M shouldn't it? I tried changing the mapping to use <C-x> and it doesn't seem to have that issue anymore. But I am still confused.

Comment: Control+M *also* acts as an enter key, but it's not the only redundancy. Control+[ corresponds with ESC. Control+I, tab. See *:h key-notation*.

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense now. I ended up mapping <C-n> for this.